# Relating arbitrary measure with Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We are given a function $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and an arbitrary measure space $(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ and the assumption that $$\int_X f d\mu<\infty.$$ We need to show that $$\int_X f d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\mu f^{-1}(t,\infty)-\mu f^{-1}(-\infty,-t) \right) d\lambda$$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure (on $\mathbb{R}$).

What I think is that we can start off by observing that $f$ is finite almost everywhere and excising such a set where $f$ is not finite, we can work with a bounded function $f$. This allows us to use approximate $f$ with a simple function as close as we like but that's all I can do. I don't even know how to show that this holds for a simple function.

Comment: Since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is finite everywhere. Maybe you mean to say there's some $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| < C$ almost everywhere, but that's not necessarily true either.

Comment: Since $f$ is real valued and measurable, we can indeed approximate it using simple functions: there exist simple functions $f_1,f_2,f_3\dots$ such that $|f_1|\leq|f_2|\leq|f_3|\dots$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise.

Comment: @aschepler The domain of $f$ is $X$. Sorry, I missed that earlier. But $f$ is finite almost everywhere by Chebyshev's inequality. After we excise the set where $f$ isn't finite, doesn't that mean $f$ is bounded on what's left of $X$?

Comment: The target space of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$ (which I'm sure is what aschepler meant), which means it is everywhere finite. But this does not mean $f$ is bounded a.e.

Comment: Oops, right. I meant the range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. duh.

Comment: When you said $\int f d\mu <\infty$  did you mean $\int |f| d\mu <\infty$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Our teacher defined the integral as the difference of the integrals of the positive and negative parts. That means both are equivalent.. right?

Comment: No. Why can't $\int f d\mu$ be $-\infty$ (which means $\int f^{+} <\infty$ and $\int f^{+} =\infty$)? (BTW a very common mistake is to write $\sum a_n <\infty$ instead of saying that the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent).

Comment: Right. I did mean that the function is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Start of by breaking $f$ into $f_+ - f_-$, where $f_+$ is strictly nonnegative, $f_-$ is strictly non-positive, and at least 1 is always zero. That is, $f_+(x) = \max(f(x), 0)$ and $f_-(x) = \min(f(x), 0)$.

Then by definition, $\int f d\mu = \int f_+ d\mu - \int f_- d\mu$.

I assume the right-side integral is in fact supposed to be taken over $\mathbb{R}_+$. Otherwise, the theorem is wrong.

Then we have $\int \mu(f^{-1}((t, \infty)) d \lambda = \int \mu(f_+^{-1}(t, \infty)) d\lambda$ and similarly, we have $\int \mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, -t)) d \lambda = \int \mu(f_-^{-1}(t, \infty)) d\lambda$. Consequently, it suffices to show that for all $f$ with nonnegative range, we have

$\int f d\mu = \int \mu(f^{-1}((t, \infty)) d\lambda$

where the integral is taken over nonnegative $t$.

This statement is clearly true for simple functions. For consider a partition $T_1, ..., T_n$ of measurable sets which $f$ maps to $r_1, ..., r_n$ respectively, with $r_1 > r_2 > ... > r_n$ (and WLOG we can set $r_n$ to be 0).

$\int f d\mu = \sum \mu(T_i) r_i$

And $\mu(f^{-1}((t, \infty))$ is a simple function sending $[r_1, \infty)$ to 0, $[r_2, r_1)$ to $\chi(T_1)$, and in general $[r_{i + 1}, r_i)$ to $\sum_{j = 1}^i \chi(T_j)$. Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \mu(T_i) r_i 
&= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \sum\limits_{j = i}^{n - 1} \mu(T_i) (r_j - r_{j + 1}) \\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n - 1} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{j} \mu(T_i) (r_j - r_{j + 1}) \\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n - 1} (r_j - r_{j + 1}) \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{j} \mu(T_i)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So the two integrals are equal whenever $f$ is a simple function. Conversely, it can be shown that whenever $t \mapsto \mu(f^{-1}((t, \infty))$ is a simple function, $f$ is a.e. equivalent to a simple function.

This is enough to prove the identity.

Comment: Showing the statement for simple functions was exactly what I was having trouble with. Please go gentle on me. Why is $f(T_i)=r_i$? Are you mapping a set to a real number?